# Spring boot devtools with Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot-devtools

Is it possible to use `spring-boot-devtools` in a `Spring MVC` project?

I basically want the `.jsp` pages and other static resources to reload automatically without server restart.

Answer (score 1):

try with these :
add a configuration bean and see if your jsp files are getting loaded

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/dist/*.js").addResourceLocations(
            "file:src/main/dist/"
        );
    }
}
```

or in the pom.xml , along with the spring-boot-maven-plugin add this

```
<configuration>
    <addResources>true</addResources>
</configuration>
```

I am not sure where you are  putting your static content in the classpath , may be in src/main/resources/public folder. Instead put them in src/main/webapp, the same as you would any other Java web app. The embedded Tomcat will automatically reload them whenever they change.